# Remove NSTableCellView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, nstablecellview

How do I maunally remove a NSTableCellView (or a subclass of it) from my NSTableView?

When i empty my array holding information, queue DB for new information and then reload the tables data, it only updates the cell with index values similar to ones found in the new array list.

ex.

I first have 8 objects in my array and they display fine. When I update my array and now only have 3, the top three cells in the table gets updated, while the last 5 remains the old ones. The old one are not selectable but only visible. And I suspect i miss some redraw/dealloc..

I tried setNeedsDisplay on the TableView but with no luck yet.

Im using ARC, Xcode 4.6.1, and OS X 10.8.3

**Sample Code**

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView {

     return [_array count];
}

- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {

     [_tableView setNeedsDisplay];

     NSDictionary *d = [_array objectAtIndex:row];
     NSString *identifier = [tableColumn identifier];

     if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"MainCell"]) {

         CustomCellView *cellView = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"MainCell" owner:self];
         [cellView.textField setStringValue:d[@"from"]];
         [cellView.subject setStringValue:d[@"subject"]];
         [cellView.text setStringValue:d[@"text"]];
         [cellView.date setStringValue:d[@"date"]];

         return cellView;
     }

     return nil;
}
```

Comment: agree with @matt - can you post the numberOfRowsInSection: and cellForRowAtIndexPath: datasource methods?

Comment: The basic recipe is this:  you have an array backing the table.  numberOfRows answers that array length, anything with indexPath in it's signature dereferences the array at indexPath.row.  Change the array and (in the simplest case) call [tableView reloadData];

Comment: I found the problem at last (after commenting almost everything out bit by bit). I had an empty drawRect in my cellView class that messed the redraw up.

Answer (score 1):

You have to tell the NSTableView to `reloadData` (it sounds like you are doing that). When you do, it is the job of the data source to know that there are now only 3 rows and to give that answer in `numberOfRowsInTableView:` (it sounds like you are not doing that). You don't show *any* code (why not?) so of course all of that is a total guess.

Comment: i do that and it returns the right amount of rows and then draws them. The problem is the views wich is based on information that does not exist anymore, are still on-screen. Im not home right now, but i can post some examples later today.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
[tableView removeRowsAtIndexSet:indexSet withAnimation:YES];
```

Comment: Wont this just remove the rows? Because I have a delegate method that informs me that the rowview has been removed. (tableView:didRemoveRowView:forRow:)

Answer (score 0):

You can (clear/refresh/redraw) you cellView with this example:

1. Create new cell with same frame as original.
2. Redraw It with the same frame as original.
3. Put the original object in it.

In this example the "mainTable" is NSTableView* of you table.

```
- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {

    NSString* identifier = [tableColumn identifier];
    NSTableCellView* cellView = [[NSTableCellView new] initWithFrame:[[mainTable makeViewWithIdentifier:identifier owner:self] frame]];

    [cellView drawRect:[[mainTable makeViewWithIdentifier:identifier owner:self] frame]];
    cellView = [mainTable makeViewWithIdentifier:identifier owner:self];

    // do something with your cellView here ...

    return cellView;
}
```